# Remote SSH access doesn't work when OpenVPN client is enabled on DD-WRT

Tags: vpn, routing, dd-wrt, remote-access, nat

I have a DD-WRT router which I would like access remotely via SSH. The DD-WRT is behind an ADSL router which has port forwarding for port 22 enabled, DD-WRT SSH access and service are set to port 22, as well. Remote access works fine. However, the DD-WRT is supposed to be permanently connected to a VPN server (using the built-in OpenVPN client).

The OpenVPN connection works fine but the remote SSH access only works when the VPN client is disabled.

I am reading that this may be related to all traffic being routed outbound through the VPN gateway, including traffic coming in through WAN. Is it correct that I would need to define a custom iptables setting for requests coming in through WAN to be responded via WAN, as well? If yes, how would I go about it? If no, what else could I do?

I am having a similar issue with the web GUI at port 8080 and a PPTP VPN server at port 1723, so I believe the issue is not related to SSH as such.

Here are the details of my setup:

**Devices:**

- TP-Link W8151N ADSL router
- TP-Link WR1043ND router with DD-WRT 25544

**IP Addresses:**

- **ADSL router external:** `115.x.x.x`
- **ADSL router internal:** `192.168.1.1`
- **DD-WRT WAN IP:** `192.168.1.100` (from ADSL router)
- **DD-WRT IP:** `192.168.10.1`
- **DD-WRT IP external (VPN):** `119.x.x.x`
- **DDNS alias pointing at the ADSL router’s connection:** `115.x.x.x`

**Configuration:**

- ADSL router with port forwarding activated for ports 22 / 8080, DDNS to `192.168.1.100`
- DD-WRT set to allow remote GUI management at 8080, also from remote IPs and SSH access at 22, SSH activated in services, also at 22.
- DD-WRT connected to OpenVPN using built-in client feature in 'Services' tab

**Edit 05 March: What I have tried in the meantime:**

Adding the following to the Policy Based Routing field in OpenVPN client settings (idea: traffic that comes from the WAN ip should be routed back to the WAN interface, vlan2 or ppp0):

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.1 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev vlan2 table 200
ip route flush cache
```

Result: When VPN connection is established, I can no longer access the GUI and the web either. My router is set to reboot after three minutes of not being able to reach Google DNS, so after three minutes I have access to GUI and web again but only until the VPN connection is back up.

Am I completely on the wrong track with this approach?

Comment: I had a similar issue with a similar question. Perhaps my answer to my question can help you: http://superuser.com/a/900575/42531

Comment: Thanks, but possible misunderstanding? Posted my own solution below two weeks ago ;-)

Comment: Opps! I noticed an unaccepted answer but not who answered it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DD-WRT go to Services --> VPN --> OpenVPN Client --> **Policy Based Routing**, add one line for each client whose traffic you want to route through the VPN tunnel, e.g.

```
    192.168.10.20/32
    192.168.10.21/32
    ...
```

As a result, the OpenVPN client no longer routes all traffic through the tunnel and hence also opens up the WAN again. I now have the VPN client running while still being able to SSH / PPTP / GUI into the router via the WAN's IP or a DDNS alias.

(There's probably a smarter way than adding one line for each client but all different netmasks that I tried resulted in the router no longer being accessible at all, so I ended up adding one line for all IPs in my DHCP range.)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't happy with the policy based routing so after a full weekend of research, I got to this.

Packages do arrive at the router if you try to SSH against the WAN IP, however, because all OUTPUT traffic is diverted through the VPN (interface `tun0`) SSH won't succeed.

What's missing is a OUTPUT rule on `iptables` to route traffic on port `22` through the `vlan2` interface (that's the interface connected directly to the internet)

```
# Create table 202 via the Gateway Ip on the Interface VLAN2
ip route add default via $(nvram get wan_gateway) dev vlan2 table 202

# Apply the rule on table 202 to packages marked with 22
ip rule add fwmark 22 table 202

# Tag with 22 every output package on port 22 not coming from any  machine in the local network
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -d ! 192.168.1.0/24 -j  MARK --set-mark 22
```

Note that the last command skips packages from the local network in my case 192.168.1.0/24, reason being that when SSHing from a host in local, the packages should be routed through `br0` and not `vlan2`.

First issue these commands in the command line of your router to ensure they work with you, if somehow they break your routing, a restart will clear them. Once you have made sure they work, you can add them to the firewall script of your router

[image: DD-WRT Config]
Note that my config IP and port is different because I am not using the default values.

Comment: Thank you!  The OUTPUT rule was what was missing in my DD-WRT config.  I run an OpenVPN client and have been trying for weeks to route traffic from several ports on one machine out the WAN with no luck.  I noticed a lot of the scripts I was finding on the forums were missing this one important step.

Comment: DD-WRT might require a restart for the rules to take full effect. If that's the case, you cannot test them in your console. Instead, you will need to add them to the Command Shell and restart to see if they work as expected. Do a config backup so you can easily restore.