# How can my home server accept and reply to connections from the Internet when OpenVPN client is running?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn, ubuntu-server

I have a headless home server running Ubuntu Server 12.04. A 3rd party website (to which I'm subscribed) periodically sends commands to a daemon on my home server which in turn responds to the 3rd party website. With static IP addressing, dynamic DNS client and port forwarding on the modem this is working as expected; All is good!

However, I now want to use OpenVPN client on my server to tunnel/route the server traffic through a 3rd party VPN server. I have successfully installed and configured OpenVPN client on my server but had found that while OpenVPN is running, the commands from the 3rd party website are either not being received by my server and/or my server is not acknowledging the command back to the 3rd party website. If I stop OpenVPN on my server it works again.

I suspect the problem is the 3rd party website sends the commands to my server (via the modem and port forwarding) but the reply is being routed over the VPN instead of back through eth0, where it came from.

The following diagram gives a basic overview of my home network.
[image]

I'm not sure what further information is needed, but hopefully the following is enough to solve the problem.

Output of ifconfig with VPN active

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:e9:08:02:17
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:e9ff:fe08:217/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:155309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:141790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:211724221 (211.7 MB)  TX bytes:20656517 (20.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2368 (2.3 KB)  TX bytes:2368 (2.3 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-   00-00-00
          inet addr:10.167.1.6  P-t-P:10.167.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:264 (264.0 B)
```

Output of `route` without OpenVPN running

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         modem           0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Output of `route` with OpenVPN running

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.111.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         modem           0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.111.1.1      10.111.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.111.1.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
us-west.private modem           255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.111.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I've found some other forums with similar sounding problems but have been unable to apply the information within to solve my specific problem.

http://www.overclock.net/t/1043127/solved-openvpn-client-blocks-inbound-ports
https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=8737

Update: I've been told to investigate policy based routing which has led me to a similar question ([Remote SSH access doesn't work when OpenVPN client is enabled on DD-WRT](https://superuser.com/questions/884081/remote-ssh-access-doesnt-work-when-openvpn-client-is-enabled-on-dd-wrt)) but so far no answer there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the VPN connects run the following

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.1 table 10
ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 table 10
```